# iMovie error when saving to camera roll

Tags: iphone, error, imovie

When ever I try to export a video from my camera roll (at whatever file size) it comes up with the message 'an error has occurred during export'.

I have tried everything I found when searching the issue, however in my phone settings -> privacy -> photos iMovie isn't an option? I don't know why and I don't know how to sort it.

I saved a video from it this morning but I now can't.

Comment: You write "... saving to camera roll ..." in the title of your question, but then write "... export a video from my camera roll ..." which are different actions.  I'm not sure where the error occurs. Does the error appear in iMovie when _saving_ to the camera roll? Does it appear while importing a movie file from the camera roll _into_ iMovie? Does the error occur while trying to export out of the iPhone?